# Informix Turbo or Online 5.0 for MS-DOS

Tags: informix

Does anyone recall if there ever was a Turbo or Online 5.0 version for MS-DOS, or was 4.10 the last released DOS version?.. I do know that the 4.10 client  was able to link to Online 5.01 and 6.0 severs on Unix, via I-NET, but unable to leverage SP's and triggers.

I'm trying to locate an Online DOS version, if one exists, so I can leverage VARCHAR's, BLOB's and other Online features not available in SE.

Answer (score 1):

There was never an Informix OnLine 5.0 for MS-DOS, AFAICR, nor any later version of Informix products.  Development for MS-DOS stopped before that.

You would not be able to obtain it very easily even if I'm wrong and it once existed (25 years or so ago).  It would only be obtainable on the second-hand market.

Comment: I know this sounds like an old broken record, but I still have one customer holding out on upgrading to Windows or Linux, even though I created an MS Access based replacement for the original app I developed in 1984 with ISQL 2.10.06 on DOS. I swear I once saw a DOS version of TURBO in 1986, but maybe I'm dreaming. That's almost 30 years ago..

Comment: Turbo was a pre-cursor to OnLine (version number 1.10.03x, whereas OnLine started at 4.00; version number(s 2 and) 3 were skipped for reasonably good reasons). There might have been an OnLine 4.x for MS-DOS; I'm almost sure there was I-Net for it, for example, but even OnLine used Unix features that might not have had an equivalent on DOS. There's an outside chance there was an OnLine 5.x for MS-DOS, though I don't think there was. There could be Windows versions. But there's (a) no chance of anything later being for DOS, and (b) even if it once existed, it will be virtually unobtainable.